# How can I correctly install multiple non-package Distribute/virtualenv/pip ecosystems on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, python, development

I am developing Python applications in Ubuntu. I want to setup a [Distribute/virtualenv/pip ecosystem](http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html#creating-a-micro-ecosystem-with-virtualenv) to manage my Python packages independently of any system Python packages (which I manage in Synaptic, or rather I let the system manage them for me).

I could just install the python-setuptools, python-virtualenv and python-pip system packages and be on my merry way, but I also want to be able to get latest/specific versions of Distribute, virtualenv and pip. There are no PPAs for these, so I'll have to install them manually.

A final complication, is that I want to be able to do this for multiple versions of Python. That is, set up one ecosystem for python2.6, another for python, another for python3, or on a 64-bit system another for [chrooted 32-bit Python](http://blog.mfabrik.com/2010/08/03/running-32-bit-chroot-on-64-bit-ubuntu-server-to-reduce-python-memory-usage/).

I'm guessing that the process would be something like:

- Using Python X install my own copy of Distribute to a location in my home folder
- Using indie Distribute, easy_install pip
- Using indie pip, install virtualenv
- Using indie virtualenv, create virtual environment
- Activate virtual environment, install packages
- Repeat for Python Y, Z and Q

What installation/configuration options am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org) does much or all of what you're asking for.  It is very popular based on the traffic here and at stackoverflow. It has been packaged in Ubuntu since Precise / 12.04.

> virtualenvwrapper is a set of extensions to Ian Bicking’s virtualenv
>   tool. The extensions include wrappers for creating and deleting
>   virtual environments and otherwise managing your development workflow,
>   making it easier to work on more than one project at a time without
>   introducing conflicts in their dependencies.

See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551951/236081) for some examples. In your case, you seem to be looking for this virtualenvwrapper command: `mkvirtualenv --python=PYTHON_EXE` (makes a virtualenv with a specific Python executable).

Finally, there is a coordinated effort to review and update Python packaging in general and taking platform-specific use cases into account, so you may want to consider following progress in the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

- Use Package Manager to install any Python versions you require (python3, python2.6, etc)
- Download [the latest version of virtualenv .tar.gz from PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
- Follow [this system-agnostic process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812207/how-can-i-correctly-install-multiple-non-package-distribute-virtualenv-pip-ecosys/6875127#6875127) to create virtual environments with pip and Distribute installed. (Link includes an Ubuntu-specific script, may work on other Linuxes too.)