# How to install a different version of python-dev?

Tags: apt, python, development

The default python version on my ubuntu system is 2.7, but 2.6 is still present.

I've installed headers (`apt-get install python-dev`), since it's needed to compile and install python packages, for current version.

However, some of my projects still run on a 2.6 virtual python environment. For them, I cannot install eggs and packages since, among others, Python.h is missing. Do I need to install an older version of python-dev? How to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing python2.6 and python2.6-dev.

Comment: tnx allot! it was simply a matter of use the correct apt-get commands!

Answer (score 3):

You can use python [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) in order to separate the different versions and packages of python you need to run.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53207/how-can-i-correctly-install-multiple-non-package-distribute-virtualenv-pip-ecosys) also deals with a similar problem.

There is also a bash script for installing and switching versions of python on the fly. If I remember the name of it I will edit this post. You can use that as well as Virtualenv to completely change python environments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812471/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-rubys-rvm

Answer (score 0):

My instinctual response would be you'd need to install python from source, typically this installs to different target locations on the drive so you should be fine. I found a link a that might help you compile from source.

http://diveintopython.org/installing_python/source.html